# How to get only the first value of a field in a Views template

Tags: 7, views

I'm using Views 3.0 and I'm trying to access a field which allows users to upload 3 photos. When I type `print $fields['field_productshots']->content;` it displays all 3 product photos. Is there a way to limit it to just the first image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When editing the view, there's an option for Multiple field settings. By default view is going to set it up to Display All starting at zero.

You can easily change it to display 1 starting at zero. This will only show the 1st image now.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! So there's really no code version for this is there? It all has to go through the Drupal CMS?